# Does Absolute Rest Imply Absolute Simultaneity in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

In Special Relativity, absolute rest implies absolute simultaneity. In other words, although simultaneity is standardly taken to be relative to an inertial reference frame, if you think there are absolute/objective facts about which things are at rest (e.g. have zero velocity), then one inertial reference frame will be unique in getting the facts about absolute rest correct, and then that "correct" reference frame can be used to define a notion of absolute simultaneity.

I'm curious about whether the same implication holds in General Relativity. If there are facts about absolute rest in General Relativity, does that imply that there is an absolute notion of simultaneity? More precisely, consider a four-dimensional manifold in General Relativity that can be decomposed into a privileged class of "absolute rest world lines", where each absolute rest world-line corresponds to an object at absolute rest (zero velocity). Can one use this decomposition of the four-dimensional manifold in terms of absolute rest world lines to define a unique global foliation of the manifold corresponding to facts about absolute simultaneity?

Comment: There is no absolute rest or absolute simultaneity in relativity.

Comment: One could also formulate the question as: does a given standard of rest imply a given standard of simultaneity? It’s true that the orthodox view is that there is no absolute rest, but historically people like Newton believed in absolute rest, and some people still think that there is absolute rest for philosophical reasons.

Comment: " _historically people like Newton believed in absolute rest, and some people still think that there is absolute rest for philosophical reasons_ " Yes, people HISTORICALLY believed it, the only people who still believe this are non mainstream crackpot theorists

Comment: The Neo-Lorentzian interpretation of special relativity implies a preferred frame of reference, and many non-crackpots have given reasons to prefer the Neo-Lorentzian interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

This might just be vocabulary, but you do not have absolute time even in special relativity.

In classical mechanics, absolute time means that if you synchronizes everybody's clocks, they stay synchronized. It doesn't matter which frame of reference you use, everybody agrees on what time it is.

You are getting at a similar idea by choosing one frame of reference to be "absolute". Everybody at rest in that frame agrees on what time it is. But that isn't what is meant in physics by absolute.

In general relativity, it is even more problematic. For example, there are no observers in the interior of a black hole at rest with respect to observers outside it.

Comment: Yes, I think this might be vocabulary. Maybe I should have said “objective”. I meant that in SR, if there are objective facts about what is at rest and what is not, then there are objective facts about which events are simultaneous and which aren’t (namely, whatever the objectively correct rest frame says is simultaneous). I was wondering if the same holds for GR.

Comment: " _I meant that in SR, if there are objective facts about what is at rest and what is not, then ................_ "  There are no such objective fact about what is at rest and what is not. " _whatever the objectively correct rest frame says is simultaneous._ " There is no objectively correct rest frame

Comment: Responding to a question of the form “if F, then G”? by rejecting F does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

A point to bear in mind is that motion can only be defined relatively. The concept of absolute rest is meaningless- it is directly comparable to the concept of absolute height: there always has to be a datum point from which a height is measured.

To extend the analogy, the concept of objective simultaneity is no more meaningful than the concept of level. If I determine that two objects are level (ie are situated at the same height) that is only true in relation to the direction I have arbitrarily chosen for my Z-axis.